# HOw to set default value in text box VB+

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2012

I am working On VB and Arduino At same time. My main intention is to get data serially displayed on Textbox of VB

Now i wanted to how can assign string or Serial data out put to textbox. 
I have google it but the sytax is not working
I created simple textbox AND  assigned variable abcd , Now i wanted to display Abcd on text box.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        TextBox1.Text = "ABCD"
    End Sub
```

If i wanted to read serial data display it on textbox

```
Private Sub Current_Read_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
        Current_Read.Text = str
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub
```

So why it not working

Comment: What do you mean by "default value"? what does "not working" mean? if you want a starting value just set the `.Text` property in the Designer or in Form Load event; the textChanged event is almost certainly not what you want

Comment: Textbox is for editing data. If you want only to display data, set the `ReadOnly` property to true.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't result as you expected because the code which you are using will executed only when you type any thing in the `textbox`, while using this code you can't able to type anything in the textbx when you type any thing in it will result in `"ABCD"`. to avoid this 
Move this code `TextBox1.Text = "ABCD"` from `TextBox1_TextChanged` event to `form_Load` event. that is

```
  Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       TextBox1.Text = "ABCD"
  End Sub
```

Comment: can you complete syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this for some reason. Add a button and double click the button so you can write your code to the event Button_Click

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SerialPort1.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
    Current_Read.Text = str
    SerialPort1.Close()
End Sub
```

run the application. and click the button